# Non-brute force regex to remove commas numbers in CSV list

Tags: regex

The main thing I am trying to do here is learn regex so that I have a better understanding of it.  What I am trying to do is a find and replace using regex to remove only the commas that are within the numbers.

I can do this using multiple find/replace patterns, and I can also do this using a brute force method of matching a large number and ignoring commas, however I am wondering if there is some way to place the numbers and comma into a capture group but ignore the commas from output.

Here is an example of a list of numbers:

```
"7,033.00","0.00","7,033.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00",1,1,1,!!$,,"123,123,123.00","123,444,38.01"
```

So my 'brute-force' method is the following:

```
\"([0-9]+)[,]?([0-9]*)[,]?([0-9]*)[,]?([0-9]*[.]+[0-9]+)\"
```

This would account for any number up to `999,999,999,999.00`.  It contains the four capture groups `$1$2$3$4` and will output any number I would expect in the format that I want.

Example of wanted output using a replace of `$1$2$3$4`:

```
7033.00,0.00,7033.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1,1,1,!!$,,123123123.00,12344438.01
```

What I would like to do is something like this (pseudo code):

```
[\"]([0-9]+)([(?:,)[0-9]*][.]+[0-9]+)[\"]
```

The idea behind this is:

1. Match the first quotation mark but ignore it
2. Match a group of numbers and place in capture group $1
3. Match either a number or comma followed by a period and one or more numbers and store in a capture group, **but** leave the commas out of the capture group.
4. Match the last quotation mark but ignore it

I've been reading and reading but can't seem to find a way to ignore part of a capture group the way I want to do it.  Any suggestions or can it not be done?

A two step method would be to match the commas first then remove the quotes, which might work too:

```
(,)(?=([0-9]{2,3}[.,]))
```

Comment: Does that mean you also want to remove the quotes? And mentioning the language you're using will be helpful too, since different regex implementations have different features.

Comment: Why do you want to use a regex for this? A CSV parser could handle the quoted strings, all you then have to do is remove all the commas.

Comment: You could just simply use this: `(,)(?=[0-9])`.  But that would not remove the quotes.  Do you want to remove the quotes also?

Comment: If it *has*  to be regex, would it be OK to do it in two steps?

Comment: Yes would also like to remove the quotes, I am just using http://www.regexr.com/ to mess around in.  I would like to use regex just because I would like to see if it can be done for the sake of knowledge, I do have another solution with a CSV parser.  Two steps would be OK but I was just seeing if Regex has the ability to leave a specified character out of a capture group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, regexr uses ECMAScript regex, so you might use something like

```
"|([0-9]),(?=[0-9])(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*"[^"]*$)
```

And replace with `$1`.

[regexr demo](http://regexr.com?385kn)

Otherwise, with PCRE, you might use something like:

```
"|(?<=[0-9]),(?=[0-9])(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*"[^"]*$)
```

And replace with nothing, where it makes use of lookarounds to make sure that the comma in question is surrounded by `[0-9]` (ECMAScript doesn't support lookbehinds currently).

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/pE1bL7)

`"` matches a literal quote character.

`|` means OR, so the regex matches a `"` or a `([0-9]),(?=[0-9])` (or `(?<=[0-9]),(?=[0-9])`)

`([0-9])` is a capture group to get one digit.

`,` matches a literal comma.

`(?=[0-9])` is a positive lookahead and ensures that the comma is followed by a digit, without matching the digit itself.

`(?<=[0-9])` is a positive lookbehind and ensures that the comma is preceded by a digit, again without matching the digit itself.

`(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*"[^"]*$)` ensures that there are an odd number of quotes ahead, and this in turn means that this will match a comma only within quotes, assuming that there are no unbalanced or escaped quotes.

Comment: But there are unquoted numbers in the string, see `1,1,1` in the middle. You don't want to remove those commas.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Didn't notice those small numbers in there, oops :s

Comment: The first solution with regexr doesn't seem to affect the small numbers, so not sure if this was edited but it seems to work -- Thank you going to make sure I understand what you did there.

Comment: @akevit I did edit it after seeing Tim's comment. I added the last lookahead, but it might be a bit complicated to understand, so if you want me to break it further down, I can do that.

Answer (score 1):

In two steps:

First remove all commas within quotes (i.e. commas that are followed by an odd number of quotes. This even works with escaped quotes since in CSV files, quotes are escaped by doubling):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '"7,033.00","0.00","7,033.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00",1,1,1,!!$,,"123,123,123.00","123,444,38.01"'
>>> s = re.sub(r',(?!(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)', '', s)
>>> s
'"7033.00","0.00","7033.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00",1,1,1,!!$,,"123123123.00","12344438.01"'
```

Then remove all the quotes:

```
>>> s.replace('"', '')
'7033.00,0.00,7033.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1,1,1,!!$,,123123123.00,12344438.01'
```

Comment: Thanks I will look into this one too.  My understanding of regex was already foggy enough but these double uncaptured captures are a bit confusing.